# How to perform mathematical operation with matrices using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

given a matrix A having 'T' rows and 'S' columns.

I want to perform

[image: the formula]

Will it be possible to create a mask and then apply to the matrix?

I am new to tensorflow.
Can somebody help me with this ??

Comment: I don't know how to do it in tensorflow but probably with `numpy.array()` or `pandas.dtaframe()` it could be done. External sum t=1...T would need only `dt.sum()`, internal sum probably would need `df.apply(func, axis=1)`. It is much easier when you create minimal example data (and expected result) which we can use for test ideas. And put example data as text - not image.

Comment: You will probably find that TF is not going to be incredibly useful here, because the second sum sums different numbers of elements for each iteration. You can of course use TF, but you won't find any fancy function that does this for you. Just iterate and if you need it for speed throw a @tf.function() on it for graph compilation

Comment: Please provide a minimal example data along with the expected results and what you have tried.

Comment: You could, precompute your indices, then use [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather).